# what are the different upload mechanisms

Tags: ajax, html, node.js, file-upload

What are the different types of upload mechanisms?

HTML 5 File API, Forms, Ajax? What are the differences for the backend implementation?

The Backend is written in node.js.

Answer (score 0):

You have two options. The first one is using a form, the second one is `xmlhttprequest`.

The `form` method: you can use an iframe so you can have a 'transparent' file upload (means user won't see a page-refresh or similar).

The `xmlhttprequest` is supported only by newer browsers, so you must decide which browsers will be able to upload files...

That said, there are a few JavScripts that will do everythin for you (detect if `xmlhttprequest` is supported, if yes, use it, if no, use iframe).
See [jQuery File Upload](http://blueimp.github.com/jQuery-File-Upload/) for example.